# Use arrayformula when converting data to grid (via filter)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to convert some raw data in the form:
`label1 | label2 | value` into a grid with label1 as one axis and label2 as the other.

Right now, I'm using the formula `=IFERROR(FILTER(raw!$C$1:$C, raw!$A$1:$A=$A2, raw!$B$1:$B=B$1), "")` (i.e. pull the one value that matches both tho row header and column header and replace with blank if that value does not exist) copy+pasted across the entire spreadsheet to handle this, however, I'd like to do this with an arrayformula if possible to avoid having to re copy+paste it to every cell whenever I change the data.

Example sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCocAaSPaof8S5Ps4upcXab-9At5XhwvK4VBE5xsVB8/edit?usp=sharing

My actual reason for making the grid is taking summary data from bigquery and converting it to a chart, so if there is a better way to do that, I'd love to know that as well.

Comment: Pivot Tables were invented for that. What is keeping you from making one?

Comment: I think his issue is that he is trying do display text data pivoted.

Comment: Honestly, this was just my total ignorance that pivot tables were a thing.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out pivot tables are exactly what I needed...I just didn't know what they were called.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pivot without aggregation.

It's a bit overkill but I have [this code](https://github.com/RobinGertenbach/Reshape) that adds two functions MELT (to unpivot tables) and CAST (to pivot without aggregation) to Google Sheets.

If you copy that code into your project (I haven't published it as an add-on yet, I ought to do it) you can then simply achieve your desired output with `=CAST(A1:C11, B1, C1)`.